# Powershell and SQL Server - set nocount

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, nocount

I am writing a powershell function to retrieve a list of students from our database but the first item returned is always the number of records. I can't figure out a way to incorporate the set nocount on into the the script - any ideas?

The function so far is:

```
Function CheckMIS{
  $Table = new-object System.Data.DataTable
  $sqlConn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=blah blah")
  $adapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(
     "select txtSchoolID,
             intSystemStatus,
             txtForename, txtSurname,
             txtForm
      from TblPupils
      where intSystemStatus = 1 ",$sqlConn)
  $adapter.Fill($Table)
  $sqlConn.Close()
  write-output $table
}
```

It returns a lovely table - but the first line is always the number of records first.
I just need to suppress that output.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the rowcount for later use.

```
$rowCount = $adapter.Fill($Table)
```

Or just ignore it.

```
$adapter.Fill($Table)  | Out-Null
```

Adding "Set Nocount On; select txtSchoolID,"... didn't have any effect in my test.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to your SQL.

i.e. `SET NOCOUNT ON select txtSchoolId, intSystemStatus,
             txtForename, txtSurname,
             txtForm
      from TblPupils
      where intSystemStatus = 1`